# PHP warning message exposes OAuth app secret

Tags: php, security, error-handling

I'm using OAuth2 to authorize Facebook accounts for an app. I just discovered that if the access token request fails, `file_get_contents` is showing the complete request URL which contains sensitive data such as the secret app id (client_id / client_secret).
How to handle such things? Is there a way to show the warning message but without exposing those paths?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=123&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Foauth%2Ffacebook.php&client_secret=123&code=123) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in oauth/facebook.php on line 113
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block to handle the errors softly in php. Since you are using Facebook OAuth, just include the method/function with in try catch as following

`try {
    "...facebook oauth function here..."
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}`

Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Regards,
HBK